# How to pass arguments to an inline script in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting, eval

I'm new to PowerShell scripting. I was wondering if there was a way to invoke a script inline without creating a new `.ps1` file and pass arguments to it, e.g.

```
powershell -command "echo `$args[0]" 123 456
```

I want `echo $args[0]` to be the script and `123 456` to be the arguments, but PowerShell seems to interpret `123 456` as part of the script (as if I'd wrote `` "echo `$args[0] 123 456" ``) and prints

```
123
456
```

Is it possible to work around this without creating a new PowerShell script on disk?

Comment: From within PowerShell you could do `powershell.exe -command {echo $args[0]} -args 123,456`

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Answer (score 1):

So far you have seen a couple answers and comments showing you how to do just what you asked for. But I have to echo @BillStewart's comment: what is your true purpose?

If it is to be able to execute some arbitrary PowerShell that you have in a string, you could certainly invoke powershell.exe, as you have seen in a couple answers and comments. However, if you do that be sure to include the `-noprofile` parameter for improved efficiency. And for even more efficiency, you could use `Invoke-Command`  without having to spin up a whole separate PowerShell environment, e.g.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([Scriptblock]::Create('echo $args[0]')) -arg 123, 456
```

If, on the other hand, you want to execute a chunk of PowerShell (*not* within a string but just separate in your script for whatever reason), you can simplify to this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {echo $args[0]} -arg 123, 456
```

Whenever you have the choice though, *avoid manipulating strings as executable code* (in any language)! The oft-used way to do that in Powershell is with `Invoke-Expression`, which I mention *only* to point you to the enlightening article [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This does what I think you want:

```
powershell -command "& {write-host `$args[0] - `$args[1] - `$args[2]}" 123 456 789
```

Each element of the $args array is a different parameter so to access three parameters you need $args[0], $args[1], and $args[2].

You could also use the param statement and get named parameters:

```
powershell -command "& {param(`$x,`$y); write-host `$x - `$y}" -x 123 -y 456
```